# Viewpager adapter not changing views

Tags: android, android-viewpager

i have an activity with actionbarsherlock TabsNavigation (3 tabs) and when I press a tab i change the viewpager adapter of the corresponding fragment. it is working fine, the thing is that when I click on another tab besides the first created, the first page is always the one of that first tab. I tried to put invalidate() before changing the adapter, but it isnt working. anyone has any idea? here is the code:

```
public class Tabsteste2 extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements TabListener {


static AdapterOpiniao mOdapter;
static  AdapterDados mDdapter;
static  AdapterFoto mFdapter;
Bundle extras;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
SharedPreferences mPrefs;

static   ViewPager mPager;
static  int countopiniao;
static int countdados;
static int countfoto;
JSONArray perguntas = null;
PageIndicator mIndicator;
static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> opiniaolist;
static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dadoslist;
static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> fotolist;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabsteste2);
    opiniaolist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    dadoslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    fotolist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    Boolean opiniaoflag = extras.getBoolean("opiniaoflag");
    Boolean dadosflag = extras.getBoolean("dadosflag");
    Boolean fotoflag = extras.getBoolean("fotoflag");
    countdados= extras.getInt("countdados");
    countopiniao=extras.getInt("countopiniao");
    countfoto=extras.getInt("countfoto");
    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("mPrefs1",MODE_PRIVATE);
    Log.d("countdados",""+countdados);
    Log.d("countfoto",""+countfoto);
    Log.d("countopiniao",""+countopiniao);

getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    if(opiniaoflag==true){
    ActionBar.Tab opiniaotab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
    opiniaotab.setText("Opinião");
    opiniaotab.setTag("op");
    opiniaotab.setTabListener(this);
    mOdapter = new AdapterOpiniao(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Log.d("Opiniao",""+opiniaotab.getTag());
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(opiniaotab);
    }if(dadosflag == true){
    ActionBar.Tab dadostab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
    dadostab.setText("Dados");
    dadostab.setTag("dd");

    mDdapter = new AdapterDados(getSupportFragmentManager());
    dadostab.setTabListener(this);
    Log.d("Dados",""+dadostab.getTag());
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(dadostab);
    }
 //   mDdapter = new AdapterDados(getSupportFragmentManager());
    if(fotoflag==true){
    ActionBar.Tab fotostab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
    fotostab.setText("Fotos");
    fotostab.setTag("ft");        
    mFdapter = new AdapterFoto(getSupportFragmentManager());
    fotostab.setTabListener(this);
    Log.d("Foto",""+fotostab.getTag());
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(fotostab);
    }


   new getpergunta().execute();


}
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
if(tab.getTag().equals("op")){
   mPager.invalidate();
   mPager.setAdapter(mOdapter);
   mIndicator = (UnderlinePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
   mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

}else if (tab.getTag().equals("dd")){
   mPager.invalidate();
   mPager.setAdapter(mDdapter);
   mIndicator = (UnderlinePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
   mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
   }else if(tab.getTag().equals("ft")){
       mPager.invalidate();
       mPager.setAdapter(mFdapter);
       mIndicator = (UnderlinePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
       mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
   }
 }


@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
}
public static class AdapterOpiniao extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public AdapterOpiniao(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return countopiniao;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return FragmentOpinioes.newInstance(position);
    }
}
public static class AdapterDados extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public AdapterDados(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return countdados;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return FragmentDados.newInstance(position);
    }
}   
public static class AdapterFoto extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public AdapterFoto(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return countfoto;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return FragmentFotos.newInstance(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: try:
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object)
    {
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your case, I used:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {   
    this.mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
```

When a click on a tab, the view of the corresponding tab is automatically changed.

**Edit:** I must admit that I have some difficulties to really understand your code and what you are trying to do, so I add some more code to explain what i think you need.

In my optinion, only one adapter is necessary for the ViewPager, and then if I'm right, you would do so:

```
// I took some personal code for my example
private ViewPager mPager;
private PageIndicator mIndicator;
private TabsExampleSectionsAdapter mAdapter;

// Inside the onCreate method
this.mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
this.mIndicator = new TabPageIndicator(this);
this.mAdapter = new TabsExampleSectionsAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager());

this.mPager.setAdapter(this.mAdapter);
this.mIndicator.setViewPager(this.mPager);
```

When everything is initialized, this is how to build tabs and pager views instructions (the two are related). Also, don't mind the Section class, it's a custom data model object which contains the tag data you need but it has nothing to do with actionbarsherlock.

```
private void buildTabs(Section[] sections) {

    if (sections != null) {

        for (Section section : sections) {

            ActionBar.Tab sectionTab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
            sectionTab.setText(section.name);
            sectionTab.setTabListener(this);
            getSupportActionBar().addTab(sectionTab);

            // The tag ("op" or "dd" in your case for example) is contained somewhere in the section object
            this.mAdapter.getSections().add(section);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the view pager adapter. It will choose what type of fragment to return following the tags you defined for each tab position:

```
public class TabsExampleSectionsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Section> mSectionsList = new ArrayList<Section>();

    public TabsExampleSectionsAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            // Retrieving the cooresponding tag of position
            Section section = this.mSectionsList.get(position % getCount());

            // Here, you check the tag to know what type of fragment you must return
            if (section.getTag().equals("dd")) {
                return FragmentDados.newInstance(position);
            } else if (section.getTag.equals("op")) {
                return FragmentOp.newInstance(position);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.mSectionsList.size();
    }

    @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return this.mSectionsList.get(position % getCount()).name.toUpperCase();
    }

    public ArrayList<Section> getSections() {
        return this.mSectionsList;
    }
}
```

In conclusion, when everything is set up, changing views doesn't have to be done manually by changing adapters and calling invalidate(). You can return different type of fragments from your adapter with a simple condition. Then, by calling:

```
this.mPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

it changes automatically the current view by passing in the adapter's getItem(position) method. Basically, you just have to coordinate your tab positions and your tags in order to get the right type of fragment.

Feel free to ask for more details.